# Почему не работает передача children

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const path = require ( 'path' );
const HTMLWebpackPlugin = require ( 'html-webpack-plugin' );
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require ( 'clean-webpack-plugin' );
// const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require ( 'mini-css-extract-plugin' );
const OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin = require ( 'optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin' );
const TerserWebpackPlugin = require ( 'terser-webpack-plugin' );
const { BundleAnalyzerPlugin } = require ( 'webpack-bundle-analyzer' );


const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development';
const isProd = !isDev;

const optimization = () => {
  const config = {
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: 'all'
    }
  };
  if ( isProd ) {
    config.minimizer = [
      new OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin (),
      new TerserWebpackPlugin ()
    ];
  }
  return config;
};

const filename = ext => isDev ? `[name].${ ext }` : `[name].[hash].${ ext }`;

const cssLoaders = ( extra ) => {
  const loaders = [
    {
      loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
      options: {
        hmr: isDev,
        reloadAll: true
      }
    }, 'css-loader'
  ];
  if ( extra ) {
    loaders.push ( extra );
  }
  return loaders;
};

const babelOptions = preset => {
  const opts = {
    presets: [
      '@babel/preset-env'
    ],
    plugins: [
      '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties'
    ]
  };

  if ( preset ) {
    opts.presets.push ( preset );
  }

  return opts;
};

const plugins = () => {
  const base = [
    new HTMLWebpackPlugin ( {
      template: './public/index.html',
      minify: {
        collapseWhitespace: isProd
      }
    } ),
    new CleanWebpackPlugin (),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin ( {
      filename: filename ( '.css' )
    } )
    // new CopyWebpackPlugin ([
    //   {
    //     from:'',
    //     to: ''
    //   }
    // ])
  ];
  if ( isProd ) {
    base.push ( new BundleAnalyzerPlugin () );
  }
  return base;
};

module.exports = {
  context: path.resolve ( __dirname, 'src' ),
  mode: 'development',
  entry: [ '@babel/polyfill', './index.jsx' ],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve ( __dirname, 'dist' ),
    filename: filename ( '.js' )
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [ '.js', '.jsx', '.json' ],
    alias: {
      '@src': path.resolve ( __dirname, 'src' ),
      '@components': path.resolve ( __dirname, 'src/components' ),
      '@pages': path.resolve ( __dirname, 'src/pages' ),
      '@assets': path.resolve ( __dirname, 'src/assets' ),
      '@media': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/utils/media'),
      '@utils': path.resolve ( __dirname, 'src/utils' ),
      '@commonStyles' : path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/styles/commonStyles'),
      '@swiper' : path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')
    }
  },
  optimization: optimization (),
  devtool: isDev ? 'inline-source-map' : 'source-map',
  plugins: plugins (),
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: cssLoaders ()
      },

      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: {
              limit: 8192,
            },
          },
        ],
      },

      {
        test: /\.(ttf|woff|woff2|eot)$/,
        use: [ 'file-loader' ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        loader: 'svg-inline-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: babelOptions ()
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.jsx$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: babelOptions ( '@babel/preset-react' )
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: 'dist/',
    hot: true,
    inline: false,
    proxy: [
      {
        context: [ '/api' ],
        target: 'http://localhost:8000',
        pathRewrite: {
          '^/api/': '/',
        },
      },
    ],
  }


};
```

Если без `div  { ...children }` то работает. Webpack собирал сам. Проблема в сборке?

```
import React from 'react';
import SwiperId from '../../core/swiper';

const SliderSmall = () => {

  return (
    <SwiperId>
      <h1>Hello</h1>
    </SwiperId>
  );
};


export default SliderSmall;
```

```html
import React, { memo } from 'react';


const SwiperId = ( { children, params } ) => {
  return (
    <div>
      { children }
    </div>
  );
};

export default SwiperId;
```

Comment: @Denis Bubnov  я упростил свой код. В данном случае ожидаю отрисовки hello

Answer (score 4):

Приведенный код - рабочий, ошибок нет. Если поместить его в сниппет - отрендерится заветная надпись `Hello!` в тэге `h1`, который в свою очередь будет обернут `div`-ом. Рабочий фрагмент кода в сниппете прилагаю:

```js
const SliderSmall = () => {
  return (
    <SwiperId>
      <h1>Hello!</h1>
    </SwiperId>
  );
};

const SwiperId = ( { children, params } ) => {
  return (
    <div>
      { children }
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <SliderSmall />, 
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<!-- The content rendered into this tag should match the content below. -->
<div id="app"></div>
```

Некоторые компоненты не знают своих потомков заранее. Это особенно характерно для таких компонентов, которые представляют из себя как бы «*коробку*», в которую можно что-то положить.

Для таких компонентов рекомендуется использовать специальный проп `children`, который передаст дочерние элементы сразу на вывод:

```
const SwiperId = ( { children } ) => {
  return (
    <div>
      { children }
    </div>
  );
};
```

Это позволит передать компоненту произвольные дочерние элементы, вложив их в JSX:

```
const SliderSmall = () => {
  return (
    <SwiperId>
      <h1>Hello</h1>
    </SwiperId>
  );
};
```

Всё, что находится внутри JSX-тега `<SwiperId>`, передаётся в компонент `SwiperId` через проп `children`. Поскольку `SwiperId` рендерит `{props.children}` внутри `<div>`, все переданные элементы (в данном случае один тэг `h1`) отображаются в конечном выводе.

Ссылка на источник: [ReactJS Композиция против наследования](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html)

P.S.: чтобы отрендерить проп `children`, достаточно просто написать `{ children }` в JSX разметке, как показано в примере выше. Не нужно писать вот так: `{ ...children }`, используя деструктурирующее присваивание.

---

В дополнение, полезные ссылки по `babel-loader` (также удостоверьтесь, что код компонент написан в файлах с расширением `.jsx`, вероятнее всего проблема в конфигурировании сборки webpack):

- [babel-loader jsx SyntaxError: Unexpected token](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33460642/5275890)
- [Babel file is copied without being transformed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33440848/5275890)

Ставим пару пакетов:

```
npm install babel-loader babel-preset-react
```

После этого конфигурируем webpack (module -> loaders):

```
{
    test: /\.jsx?$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: ['react']
        }
      }
    ],
  }
```

И не забываем про пресеты в `.babelrc` файле:

```
presets:['es2015','react']
```

Более подробную информацию можно посмотреть в прикрепленных ссылках или в туториалах на подобии: *«How to set up React, webpack, and Babel»*

Comment: всеравно не работает. Скинул фото ошибки.

Comment: @Slavick ошибку нужно прикреплять не в ответ, а в Ваш вопрос. Удостоверьтесь в том, что расширение у вашего файла `.jsx` а также в том, что в вебак конфиге у вас настроен лоадер для jsx через `babel-loader`. Ссылка: [babel-loader](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/issues/198#issuecomment-172361171)

Comment: @ Denis Bubnov скинул код webpack, к вопросу дополнил, посмотрите пожалуйста, вроде все стоит

Comment: @Slavick Навскидку скажу, что конфигрирование webpack у вас написано не лучшим образом. Но повторюсь. У вас у файлов правильное расширение? `SliderSmall` и `SwiperId` написаны в файлах с расширением `.jsx`, вы случайно не в `.js` их записали? И вынесите presets в отдельный файл `.babelrc`, ваш `options: babelOptions ( '@babel/preset-react' )` аж глаза режет.

Comment: Спасибо большое!!! Там действительно расширение js стояло

Comment: @Slavick прикрепите к своему вопросу ошибку - это первое. Второе - удостоверьтесь, что все необходимые пакеты для `babel` у вас установлены. Третье - напишите конфиг вебпака с нуля, используя какой-нибудь туториал, ибо в вашем файле легко запутаться. Третье - пресеты вынести в отдельный файл. Четвертое - не нужно писать кучу переменных в вебак конфиге, они только добавляют неясностей. И в заключение - посмотрите ссылки, которые я вам прикрепил в ответе.

Comment: можно поросить Вас о менторстве?

Comment: @Slavick увы, но нет. Здесь я бываю, когда есть свободная *минутка* на работе. Думаю на SO Вам смогут помочь, просто старайтесь писать более подробные вопросы. И самое главное - не отчаивайтесь, все проходили путь обучения 